# Import error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, import, path

I'm brand new to MATLAB and am having trouble importing a module called sigTOOL. My code:

```
>> path('/space/jazz/1/users/gwarner/sigTOOL/program')
>> sigTOOL
```

returns:

```
Undefined function 'fileparts' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in sigTOOL (line 72)
parentdirectory=fileparts(which('sigTOOL'));
```

The weirdest part is that I've actually been able to open this successfully before. I used the same code and haven't edited the sigTOOL directory or changed it's path since. Any ideas?

Comment: Check that you don't have a variable called `fileparts` in your workspace, or a function in your path that shadows the built-in `fileparts`.

Comment: `which fileparts` returns `'fileparts' not found.`

Is this the proper way to check if a variable is in my workspace?

Comment: And in the workspace ? Check `whos`

Comment: `>> whos fileparts`

returns nothing. It just prompts me for the next input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usage of [`path`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html) is wiping out MATLAB's default search path.
If you change the first line to

```
path(path,'/space/jazz/1/users/gwarner/sigTOOL/program')
```

the path will be added to the bottom of the search stack.  You can add the directory to the top of the stack by using [`addpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html):

```
addpath('/space/jazz/1/users/gwarner/sigTOOL/program')
```